# Android Studio mixed codes of two different Applications

Tags: android, android-studio

I was editing 2 apps at the same time. One is a new idea, where I am doing some tests and the other one that is a stable app, that eventually needs small edits.

I do not how it happened but Android Studio mixed then. In fact, AS is saying that for some activities of the second, the code is the same as the first. On the example below, even the second being java coded, it shows it as xml.

If I look at the same file outside AS, using Wordpad, for example, the code is correct, i.e. it is the original like I did  (see the picture).

I tried many things like cleaning cache, closing and opening AS, so many times, so many ways, etc. but nothing works. For days I am stuck on this issue. I tried even the function ´Compare with´ but it shows the (wrong) xml code.

Was not only this Activity that appears ´corrupted´ but others of the stable one.

Any idea?

[On Left is the beginning of the real code; on Right how AS shows it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPALK.png)

Comment: Happened with me. Close the android studio, delete the `.iml` files from `project_root, project_root/build` folder, `project_root/app/build`, `user/gradle/cache` and `user/android studio/system/cache`. And then start android studio and rebuild your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the `caches` folder in .AndrroidStudio and restart Android studio.

Path :

```
C:\Users\username\.AndroidStudio3.6\system\caches
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it does so. I met the same issue and fix it by:

On your android studio top bar, go: File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart.

I'm using android studio mac.